# How to count the number of lines that a specific word occurs in a txt file?

Tags: java

I'm not sure if this is enough code, but I am reading a txt file and I want to figure out how to print the number of lines that contain "hello".

I already printed out the lines that do contain "hello", but I need to figure out how to count those lines.

Or is there a way I can put each "hello" line into an array and then print out the array length which would also be the number of lines?

..any help would be appreciated!

```
 while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // splits each line into words
        String tokens[] = line.split(" ");
        
        for(int i= 0; i<tokens.length; i++){

            if(words[i].equalsIgnoreCase("hello")){
                System.out.println(line+"\n");
                //the above line prints out each line that contains "hello", but how would I create a variable for the number of lines

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So if a line contains the word twice, it should still only count once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably have an integer counter inside the if statement. It would iterate just before/after the line is printed with ++.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a variable that counts up:

```java
int count = 0;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // splits each line into words
    String tokens[] = line.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {

        if (words[i].equalsIgnoreCase("hello")) {
            System.out.println(line + "\n");
            count++; // count 1 up
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Number of lines containing 'hello': " + count);
```

Also,
if you want to query whether a word is in a string, you can use the `String#contains` method:

```java
int count = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // check for "hello" in string, case-sensitive
    if (line.contains("hello")) {
        count ++;
    }
}
```

If you want to ignore upper and lower case, use instead of `line.contains("hello")`: `line.toLowerCase().contains("hello")`

Comment: Id also add you could also use the equalsIgnoreCase method instaed of converting everything to lowercase but both work fine

Comment: @Matt This is not possible in the example, because I don't split the line into words - I only ask with `String#contains`, if "hello" is in the line. And since `String#contains` is case sensitive, the line must first be converted to lower-case.

Answer (score 2):

While the other solutions are perfectly valid, you can easily turn this into a one-liner, so I felt I should at least post this for comparison.  See below:

```java
System.out.println(br.lines().filter(Pattern.compile("(?i)hello").asPredicate()).count());
```

This gets a stream where each element in the stream is one line from the BufferedReader.  It then filters the stream by which lines contain "hello".  `(?i)` means case-insensitive in regular expressions.  Then it just counts the number of elements left in the stream, and prints out the result.  You could also store the result in a variable and use it later, like so:

```java
long num = br.lines().filter(Pattern.compile("(?i)Hello").asPredicate()).count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you already have your loop printing out every line that has the word "hello", and you need to count the number of these lines you go through, why don't you just.. count it :)

In other words, try initializing an integer counter and incrementing that counter for every line containing the word "hello".

Hope this helps. Not posting any code because it seems like good practice I don't want to take away from you!

Comment: I also feel like this problem doesn't really need any code along with it just because of how simple the solution is. Make an integer++, bam problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to look at a problem in pseudocode first, which gets away from the details of the language and focuses more on the solution:

```
function countLinesWith(targetWord, textFile)
  lineCount <- 0
  repeat
    thisLine <- readNextLine(textFile)
    if (thisLine.contains(targetWord) {
      lineCount <- lineCount + 1
    }
  until(textFile.EoF)
  return lineCount
end function
```

Then translate the pseudocode into your language of choice.